# I tried to run Java in Eclipse and it asks me to select ant build and either one I choose it says unable to find ant file to run...

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

[image]
So I just installed JRE, JDK and Eclipse and I was trying to run this famous HelloWorld code, but it shows this message as in attached images. What's the ant build?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is using Ant mandatory? Or you just need to run the program?
Else, right click on the Java file > Run As > Java application.

Comment: Did you meddle with `Run Configuration`?

Answer (score 4):

dont run it as ant, right click on your file in eclipse select run as then choose java application

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have your file in your buildpath (what eclipse uses to figure out what files it should compile). Right click on the folder and select Buildpath -> Use as Source folder. Now when you hit run it should hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Run
2. Run Configurations
3. Select Java Application(From Left Pane)
4. Fill Up Your Project Name and your Main Class
5. Apply and Run

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrAQA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to
Delete all eclipse files in your pc and again download eclipse and install it. Definitely works

Answer (score 0):

Click Run As > Java.

If Java is not available there, click Run Configurations > JRE.

Choose "Execution environment" , click Environments and choose the Java version you want to use. Click Apply, Run.

That should do it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a Java class file with suitable name and method.This error usually occurs when compiler doesn't understand which file to execute.

Comment: You can clearly see in the OP's screenshot that he has a public class with the required `main` method.

Answer (score -1):

Simply click the javadoc next to your console and run it

Comment: The console is not showing up in the screenshot. Do you mean the javadoc tab at the bottom? Also, why would that work? I don't see any relationship between javadoc and a run configuration.